# Take list elements until a specific number occurs $n$ times

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to take enough elements from `list` such that `2` is included `3` times.

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomChoice[{.2, .5, .3} -> {1, 2, 3}, 20]
```

> {3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2}

I hope to get `{3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2}`. I think I make no mistake in my code:

```
TakeWhile[list, Count[Append[{}, #], 2] <= 3 &]
```

But I just get `{}`.

Comment: I don't have *Mathematica* 10.1, so I can't test this, but does the following work? `First@SequenceCases[list, {Shortest[___], 2, 2}]`.

Comment: @march Actually not,but `First[SequenceCases[
  list, {Except[2] ..., 2, Except[2] ..., 2, Except[2] ..., 2}]]` work for my case,Thanks. :)

Comment: It might be worth noting that your attempt and the accepted answer will take everything before the fourth 2. In your example that's identical but for `{1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2}` you'd get `{1,2,1,2,1,2,1}`. Is that your intention?

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh,god.You give me a big remind that I have made a mistake.Actually,I want to get `{1,2,1,2,1,2}` in your case.

Comment: @yode ubpdqn's answer works like that.

Comment: @yode i feel you posted a similar question elsewhere as well http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138905/partition-a-list-by-count-a-number

Comment: @yode can you link the two questions together?

Comment: @AliHashmi Actually I have do [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/138897/2) before,but it will make this function too board.

Comment: Also `lst[[;;Position[lst,2][[3,1]]]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
i = 1; While[Count[list[[1 ;; i]], 2] < 3, i++]
list[[1 ;; i]]
```

or

```
list[[1 ;; Catenate[Position[list, 2]][[3]]]]
```

Comment: Look little consice,`i=0;While[Count[list[[1;;++i]],2]<3];list[[;;i]]`.And do you know why my `TakeWhile` don't work?

Comment: `TakeWhile` tests each element not the cumulative list. You could do something ugly like: `list[[1 ;; 
   Length@TakeWhile[
      Count[list[[1 ;; #]], 2] & /@ Range[Length[list]], # < 3 &] + 
    1]]` though I am sure others would have better ways

Comment: Yep,I know that.So I give a `Append` to collect it.

Comment: @yode but your append is in your test

Answer (score 8):

I think you meant to do this:

```
Module[{tmp = {}}, TakeWhile[list, Count[AppendTo[tmp, #], 2] <= 3 &]]
```

Comment: Thanks,I have adjust that `==`.But since `AppendTo` can work,why `Append` not?Confusing still.

Comment: Because you are always appending to `{}` whereas I am appending to `tmp`, which is hence a growing list. In my case, `tmp` contains all the elements processed so far. In your case, it's just the same as `{#}`, i.e., just the current element wrapped in `{}`

Comment: Oh,I see now.Thanks very much.

Comment: @Felix nicely instructive

Answer (score 6):

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
Take[list, Check[PositionIndex[list][2][[3]], 1 ;; -1]]
```

`Check` will substitute specs to get the entire list `1;;-1`, should the `PositionIndex` command fail.

> {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}

Comment: (+1) Nice use for `Check`!

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.1 we can also do this:

`list[[;; First@First@SequencePosition[list, {2, 2, 2}]]]`

Or to generalize:

```
takeBefore[list_,obj_,reps_]:=
  list[[;; First@First@SequencePosition[list, ConstantArray[obj,reps]]]]
```

Of course that assumes the sublist is in there. If it's not the `First` calls will whine at you:

```
In[11]:= SeedRandom[3]
list = RandomChoice[{.2, .5, .3} -> {1, 2, 3}, 20]

Out[12]= {2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}

In[13]:= list[[;; First@First@SequencePosition[list, {2, 2, 2}]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Block[{i = 1}, NestWhileList[list[[i++]] &, Nothing, (Count[{##}, 2] < 3) &, All ]]
```

> {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}

Answer (score 5):

We can define an operator `f[v, k, m]` that splits an input list every time the number of `v`s reaches `k`, and use the optional third argument `m` to get desired part(s):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[v_, k_, m_ : 1] := Module[{s = 0}, 
  Split[#, Or[(s += Boole[# == v]) < k, s = 0] &][[m]]] &
```

***Examples:***

```
f[2, 3] @ list /. 2 -> Highlighted[2]
```

[image]

```
f[2, 3, All] @ list /. 2 -> Highlighted[2]
```

[image: > {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2}}]

```
f[2, 6] @ list /. 2 -> Highlighted[2]
```

[image: > {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2}]

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `Partition`:

```
Last[
    Map[Function @ If[SameQ[Count[#, 2], 3], #, Nothing],
        Apply[Join,
            Map[Function @ Partition[list, {#}], Range @ Length @list]
        ]
    ]
 ]

(*{3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2}*)
```

The following form is courtesy of @Syed (Thanks, mate!):

```
list /. 
{k : Except[2] ...,h : OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 2, 2, 2, ___], ___} :> {k, h}

(*{3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2}*)
```

Comment: You are looking for the first consecutive occurrence of `2`. The task is to grab enough of the `list` such that three `2`s are included.

Comment: You're right, I will think hard to improve my answer.

Comment: `list /. {k : Except[2] ..., 
   h : OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 2, 2, 2, ___], ___} :> {k, h}`

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

First @ SequenceCases[list, _?(Count[#, 2] == 3 &)]
```

{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}

Answer (score 2):

yet another Sow and Reap

```
index = 1;

x = 0;

arr = {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

While[
    x <= 3
    ,
    Sow[arr[[index]]];
    index++;
    If[arr[[index]] == 2,
        x++
    ];
] //
Reap //
Last //
First
```