# Partition a list by count of a number

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I want to take this list when the `2` appear 3 times

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomChoice[{.2, .5, .3} -> {1, 2, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
> {3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2}
> ```

Hope to get `{{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2},{2}}`.I think `` GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy `` can help to do this,but I'm fail to do it.

```
i = 0; GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy[list, (If[# == 2, i++; 
    If[i == 4, i = 0]]; i === 3) &]
```

Will get nothing. Can anybody give a concise version? Of course, I will feel more happy if I get a `` GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy `` version. Because I have failed many times with it.

Comment: Though my answer is late I hope you will read and consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

SequenceCases[list, _?(Count[#, 2] == 3 &)]
```

{{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}}

Answer (score 19):

It is always good to start with `` System` `` functions:

```
Flatten /@ Partition[Split[list, #1 =!= 2 &], UpTo[3]]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2}}
> ```

alternatively:

```
Module[{i = 0},
   Sow[#, ⌊ If[# == 2, i++, i]/3 ⌋ ] & /@ list // Reap // Last
 ]
```

Comment: As all of solution,your first method deserve a acceptance still.Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 9):

Requires a touch more than just a single call to `PartitionBy`, but works:

```
Flatten /@ Partition[GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy[list, # == 2 &], UpTo[3]]
```

And here is a solution just using `PartitionBy` as you requested:

```
i = 1;
GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy[list, 
 If[# == 2, i++; Evaluate@If[i == 3, i = 0; True, False], False] &
]
```

I think the tricks are make sure the second argument returns `True` when you want a partition to be created (and `False` otherwise). And the `Evaluate` seemed to be required.

Cool idea to use `PartitionBy`!

Comment: I'm confused why we should need that `Evaluate`

Comment: We can concise it a little.``i = 1; GeneralUtilities`PartitionBy[list, 
 If[# == 2, i++; Evaluate@If[Divisible[i, 3], True]] &]``.But the `Evaluate` haunt me still.It's seem the failure before cause to it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a version using `SplitBy`.

```
Module[{i = 0}, SplitBy[lst, Floor[1/3 If[# != 2, i, i++]] &]]
```

(After reading [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s [second solutio](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138915/29734)n more carefully, it turns out that they use the same idea on their second solution, but I figure the `SplitBy` version is nice to have alongside the `Sow`/`Reap` solution.)

Answer (score 7):

Also

```
lengths = Differences@Flatten[{0, Position[list, 2][[3 ;; ;; 3]], Length@list}]; 

Internal`PartitionRagged[list, lengths]
```

> {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2}}

In versions 10 and later, you can use `FoldPairList[TakeDrop, ...]` instead of `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``.

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, list, lengths]
```

> {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2}}

Answer (score 6):

This problem is a variation of:

- [Getting lengths of sublists that sum to more than one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3908/121)
- [Partitioning a list when the cumulative sum exceeds 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105792/121)

Applying [my `Split` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105800/121):

```
list = {3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2};

Module[{n = 0}, Split[list, # != 2 || ++n < 3 || (n = 0) &]]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2}}
> ```

The obvious comparison is to march's similar code using `SplitBy`, and Kuba's `Sow`/`Reap` method:

```
SeedRandom[0]
list = RandomInteger[9, 500000];

Module[{i = 0}, SplitBy[list, ⌊1/3 If[# != 2, i, i++]⌋ &]] //
   Length // RepeatedTiming

Module[{i = 0}, Sow[#, ⌊If[# == 2, i++, i]/3⌋] & /@ list // Reap // Last] //
   Length // RepeatedTiming

Module[{n = 0}, Split[list, # != 2 || ++n < 3 || (n = 0) &]] // 
   Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {1.84, 16576}
>
> {1.137, 16576}
>
> {0.305, 16576}
> ```

So my code is at least several times faster than other manual index methods.

However `Split` itself is not very efficient, cf. [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121#23623).
Applying those faster methods here:

```
splitEvery[list_, x_, n_Integer] := (
  Unitize[list - x]
    // SparseArray[#, Automatic, 1] &
    // #["AdjacencyLists"][[n ;; ;; n]] &
    // {Prepend[# + 1, 1], Append[#, -1]} &
    // MapThread[Take[list, {##}] &, #] &
 )

splitEvery[list, 2, 3] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.021, 16576}
> ```

This is nearly an order of magnitude faster than even Kuba's `Partition` method.
(`UpTo` doesn't work in v10.1 so I use an older equivalent.)

```
Flatten /@ Partition[Split[list, #1 =!= 2 &], 3, 3, 1, {}] // 
  Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.194, 16576}
> ```

And as usual with list partitioning problems it is the partitioning itself that takes the most time.  If we can work with an interval list instead:

```
intervalEvery[list_, x_, n_Integer] := (
  Unitize[list - x]
    // SparseArray[#, Automatic, 1] &
    // #["AdjacencyLists"][[n ;; ;; n]] &
    // {Prepend[# + 1, 1], Append[#, -1]} &
    // Transpose
 )

intervalEvery[list, 2, 3] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00343, 16576}
> ```

The output of that last function:

```
intervalEvery[{3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2}, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 8}, {9, 13}, {14, 19}, {20, -1}}
> ```

Comment: Could your tell me why I always get a same list `Unitize[list - 2] // SparseArray[#, Automatic, AnyNumber] & // Normal`?Change the `AnyNumber`

Comment: @yode The third parameter of `SparseArray` sets the background element.  The `Normal` form of the `SparseArray` will always look the same.  Use `ArrayRules` to get a sense of how this works, e.g.:  `Table[ArrayRules @ SparseArray[Range@5, 5, i], {i, 5}]`

Comment: A lot of skills in your answer...but I know those all.Thanks very very much.. :)

Comment: @yode You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 5):

**here is a recursive way using tail-recursion and pattern matching**

```
Clear[func, partition,f];

func[x_List: {__}] := 
x /. {a___, patt : Repeated[PatternSequence[2, ___], {3}], c___} :> 
Join[{{a, patt}}, func[{c}]];
f := Replace[#, {a__List, x : _Integer ..} :> {a, {x}}] &;
partition[y_List] := Composition[f, func][y]

partition[{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3}]

(* {{3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {3}} *)
```